# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: enterprise-library, executenonquery

I've seen this question asked here before, but never when Enterprise Library is used. I've used code like the following before and it works fine. What's the problem this time? I get the error on the last line:

```
    Database db = new SqlDatabase(MyConfiguration.Current.ConnectionString);
    DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("AddWorkListItem");

    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@PartNumber", DbType.String, partNumber);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@Quantity", DbType.Int32, qty);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@WorkListTypeCode", DbType.String, code);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@UserKey", DbType.Int32, userKey);

    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ? https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/288036

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gosh it's been a while but I'm pretty sure you call `db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd)` rather than `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Have you tried that?

Comment: D'oh! Looks like I got my ADO.NET and EntLib wires crossed. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me!! but whats wrong with cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()?